# How to evaluate this integral involving with a variable and exponential number?

Tags: calculus

How to evaluate this with integration by parts if necessary?

$\displaystyle \int \frac {x^3e^{x^2}}{(x^2+1)^2} dx$

Comment: Have you tried any substitutions?

Comment: Hint: try the following substitution: $u=x^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First substitute $t=x^2$ to get $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{te^t}{(t+1)^2}dt$;

then use integration by parts with 
$u=te^t$ and $\displaystyle dv=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}dt$.

Answer (score 1):

We make the substitution $u=x^2$, and end up wanting
$$\int \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{ue^u}{(u+1)^2}\,du.$$
By inspection we get $\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\dfrac{e^u}{u+1}+C$.